# Dockerfile wrong directory. I don't know why

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Hello I am trying to run my react app on docker and I've encountered a problem! I am beginner at this topic so please help!

```
FROM node:16.13-slim
WORKDIR /app
RUN chown -R node:node /app
USER node
COPY --chown=node:node package.json yarn.lock /app/
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile
COPY --chown=node:node src /app
RUN yarn build
EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

[image]

my file structure is something like this

[image]

Comment: Because `Could not find required file` index.html

Comment: What's the actual problem?  How are you starting the container?  It looks like you included two image files as part of the question; how does your application generate or use those?  Could you [edit] the question to replace the images with an actual error message, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
COPY --chown=node:node public src /app
```

Add the command above, since the public directory is **not** under the src directory

By adding only the following command

```
COPY --chown=node:node src /app
```

You did not copy the public directory